# Pandas: How to transform data and change column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

i was wondering if its possible to change column values with another based on date and employee , `E/X=6` represent the time the employee has entered and `E/X=1` is the time he's out
each employee has `ID` and `Date` he can go out and enter multiple times a day

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as n

df=p.read_excel("C:/Users/Hercules/Desktop/Employee.xls")
df

ID E/X            DateTime        Date     Time
107 6 2022-01-04  10:04:18 0 2022-01-04 10:04:18
107 6 2022-01-04  11:32:52 0 2022-01-04 11:32:52
107 6 2022-01-04  11:39:59 0 2022-01-04 11:39:59
107 1 2022-01-04  12:05:26 0 2022-01-04 12:05:26
107 6 2022-01-04  18:02:18 0 2022-01-04 18:02:18
107 6 2022-01-04  18:30:38 0 2022-01-04 18:30:38
107 1 2022-01-04  19:06:58 0 2022-01-04 19:06:58
107 1 2022-01-05  12:22:10 0 2022-01-05 12:22:10
107 6 2022-01-05  19:22:15 0 2022-01-05 19:22:15
122 1 2022-01-03  08:57:40 0 2022-01-03 08:57:40
122 6 2022-01-03  12:49:33 0 2022-01-03 12:49:33
122 1 2022-01-03  13:22:28 0 2022-01-03 13:22:28
122 6 2022-01-03  16:29:51 0 2022-01-03 16:29:51
122 1 2022-01-03  16:40:06 0 2022-01-03 16:40:06
```

I want to find a solution to modify some values in `E/X` in order to calculate the appropriate working time for each employee . every day for every employee have to start with `6` and ends with `1`, also every two consecutive rows should be like this and its possbile to drop rows because the count of rows for every id in a day must me pair (he entres and then he goes out,that's the algorithm `6` and then `1` , `6` and then `1` ):

```
ID E/X             DateTime        Date     Time
107 6 2022-01-04  10:04:18 0 2022-01-04 10:04:18
107 1 2022-01-04  11:32:52 0 2022-01-04 11:32:52
```

**Desired Result**

```
ID E/X            DateTime         Date     Time
107 6 2022-01-04  10:04:18 0 2022-01-04 10:04:18
107 1 2022-01-04  11:32:52 0 2022-01-04 11:32:52
107 6 2022-01-04  11:39:59 0 2022-01-04 11:39:59
107 1 2022-01-04  12:05:26 0 2022-01-04 12:05:26
107 6 2022-01-04  18:02:18 0 2022-01-04 18:02:18
107 1 2022-01-04  19:06:58 0 2022-01-04 19:06:58
107 6 2022-01-05  12:22:10 0 2022-01-05 12:22:10
107 1 2022-01-05  19:22:15 0 2022-01-05 19:22:15
122 6 2022-01-03  08:57:40 0 2022-01-03 08:57:40
122 1 2022-01-03  12:49:33 0 2022-01-03 12:49:33
122 6 2022-01-03  13:22:28 0 2022-01-03 13:22:28

122 1 2022-01-03  16:40:06 0 2022-01-03 16:40:06
```

Comment: please fix the sample data. for instance, is this value `2022-01-04  10:04:18` 1 column or two? if its to separate columns, please update the header row. There is a `0` between column 3 `Datetime` and column 4 `Date`. What does it represent?

Comment: The 0  between `DateTime` and `Date` is unnamed column i will drop it when i clean the data . `2022-01-04  10:04:18` its 1 column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its an excel file generated from a biometric clock , i just open it

Comment: are columns `Date` & `Time` just `DateTime` split up into two? I'm trying to understand what these columns represent.

Comment: Yes indeed `Date` and `Time` generated from `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
data = {'ID': {0: 107, 1: 107, 2: 107, 3: 107, 4: 107, 5: 107, 6: 107, 7: 107, 8: 122, 9: 122, 10: 122, 11: 122}, 'E/X': {0: 6, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 6, 5: 1, 6: 6, 7: 1, 8: 6, 9: 1, 10: 6, 11: 1}, 'DateTime': {0: '04/01/2022 10:04', 1: '04/01/2022 11:32', 2: '04/01/2022 11:39', 3: '04/01/2022 12:05', 4: '04/01/2022 18:02', 5: '04/01/2022 19:06', 6: '05/01/2022 12:22', 7: '05/01/2022 19:22', 8: '03/01/2022 08:57', 9: '03/01/2022 12:49', 10: '03/01/2022 13:22', 11: '03/01/2022 16:40'}, 'Date': {0: '04/01/2022', 1: '04/01/2022', 2: '04/01/2022', 3: '04/01/2022', 4: '04/01/2022', 5: '04/01/2022', 6: '05/01/2022', 7: '05/01/2022', 8: '03/01/2022', 9: '03/01/2022', 10: '03/01/2022', 11: '03/01/2022'}, 'Time': {0: '10:04:18', 1: '11:32:52', 2: '11:39:59', 3: '12:05:26', 4: '18:02:18', 5: '19:06:58', 6: '12:22:10', 7: '19:22:15', 8: '08:57:40', 9: '12:49:33', 10: '13:22:28', 11: '16:40:06'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then, you just need to sort by:

df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date', 'Time'])

```
Thats my output:

_______

     ID  E/X          DateTime        Date      Time
0   107    6  04/01/2022 10:04  04/01/2022  10:04:18
1   107    1  04/01/2022 11:32  04/01/2022  11:32:52
2   107    6  04/01/2022 11:39  04/01/2022  11:39:59
3   107    1  04/01/2022 12:05  04/01/2022  12:05:26
4   107    6  04/01/2022 18:02  04/01/2022  18:02:18
5   107    1  04/01/2022 19:06  04/01/2022  19:06:58
6   107    6  05/01/2022 12:22  05/01/2022  12:22:10
7   107    1  05/01/2022 19:22  05/01/2022  19:22:15
8   122    6  03/01/2022 08:57  03/01/2022  08:57:40
9   122    1  03/01/2022 12:49  03/01/2022  12:49:33
10  122    6  03/01/2022 13:22  03/01/2022  13:22:28
11  122    1  03/01/2022 16:40  03/01/2022  16:40:06
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't do it manually because I have millions of rows

Comment: I used the "data" variable as sample. Import your excel data file to a pandas dataframe and sort it like I did.

Comment: it's already sorted ,  but i have errors some exits are registred as an entry